# How to secure routes in Symfony using security.yml

Tags: symfony, roles

I have this where a admin inherits user roles:

```
role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

...

access_control:

- { path: ^/index, roles: ROLE_USER }
- { path: ^/items, roles: ROLE_USER }
- { path: ^/items/edit$, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

And I am trying to make the edit page (and everything featuring the edit page... ie. /items/edit/1, /items/edit/2, etc) accessible only to admin users.

This isn't working though, I logged in as a user and I can still view the edit pages.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:** Something else I just thought of - once I get this working, how do I define which page to send the user to in the event that they are denied access? Could it be that's why it's not working now, because I haven't specified what to do in the event that a user is denied access to a page?

Comment: Remove the `$` sign which means *"end of string"* in a regexp. You also need to inverse the second and the last row because symfony will test them in the order given, and will stop at the first match.

Comment: Ah - you were right. Thanks. Changing the ordering fixed it. What about specifying a page to take the user to in the event they are denied access, is that possible? It's just an exception message right now.

Comment: That's a different question. You need to [customize](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/error_pages.html) the [403 error page](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/error_pages.html#customizing-the-404-page-and-other-error-pages)

Answer (score 1):

Remove `$` from `^/items/edit` pattern and add `$` to `^/items` pattern. Like this:

```
- { path: ^/items$, roles: ROLE_USER }
- { path: ^/items/edit, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

With `$` at the end you only restrict access exactly for `/items/edit` url and not `/items/edit/1`, `2/items/edit/2` ... .

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately that doesn't work either though. I am using app_dev.php mode, so I can see that the user is indeed a user role (Roles  [ROLE_USER] is what it says on the debug screen). What else can I do to debug this and find out what is stopping this from working?